# Showing average of a value using Bar sign in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I want to use bar sign (a line above a variable) to show the average of a variable. I found this code:

```
plot(randn(100,1)); 
ylabel('$\bar{ABCDEFG}-T5$','interpreter','latex')
```

but this line is small. Is there a way to make it same as length of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
ylabel('$\overline{ABCDEFG}-T5$', 'interpreter','latex')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh thanks it is perfect!Just One thing if I want to put it in legend what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found out for using it in legend we should say

```
legend({'$\overline{ABCDEFG}-T5$'},'interpreter','latex');
```